# xmlstarlet/bash: How to replace value of element directly in file?

Tags: xml, bash, xmlstarlet

my XML-file is like:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<agents>
  <agent id="1">
    <aname>pi1</aname>
    <alive>1</alive>
    <scenarios>1,2,3</scenarios>
  </agent>
  <agent id="4">
    <aname>pi4</aname>
    <alive>0</alive>
    <scenarios>2,5,6,25,77,88,99</scenarios>
  </agent>
...many more
</agents>
```

I figured out a xmlstarlet command to change values of an element, e.g. for element *alive* it would be:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "/agents/agent[@id=1]/alive" -v 0 agents.xml
```

Result:

```
...
<agent id="1">
        <aname>pi1</aname>
        <alive>0</alive>
        <scenarios>1,2,3</scenarios>
</agent>
...
```

The result is just printed to sdtout. I'm looking for a solution (like with SED -i) to replace the value directly in file instead of redirecting stdout to a file like:

```
xmlstarlet ed -u "/agents/agent[@id=1]/alive" -v 0 agents.xml > agents2.xml
```

At now I iterate through the whole XML-document and everytime a value is changed, I create a new XML-file (that takes a very long time). But this is not a proper solution. Thanks for any ideas!

Comment: This sounds vaguely like an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You can hardly avoid rewriting the file. If you have multiple modifications, could you queue them up into a single command so that you only  process the file once?

Comment: Btw, `sed -i` copies the file to /tmp, change the file in /tmp and overwrite your original file.

Comment: `xmlstarlet` has an `--inplace` option. see `xmlstarlet ed --help`

Comment: @triplee. Thanks, I used tripleee's advice.